# How to tell which HTML form was submitted to Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to get this to work. I have multiple submit forms on my index.html. Depending on which I click I want it to run the proper if/elif statement in my server.py file. Currently, it only works for "farm" for obvious reasons as I have buildings = to form "farm". How can I set it up to work for the appropriate statement based on which submit button I click?

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    session["my_gold"]=0
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/process_money", methods=["post"])
def money():

building = request.form["farms"]

if request.form["farms"] == building:
    print "hello"
    gold = random.randrange(10,21)
    print gold
    session["my_gold"] = session["my_gold"] + gold
    print session["my_gold"]

elif request.form["caves"] == building:
    print "goodbye"
    gold = random.randrange(5,11)
    print gold
    session["my_gold"] = session["my_gold"] + gold
    print session["my_gold"]

elif request.form["houses"] == building:
    print "wow"
    gold = random.randrange(2,6)
    print gold
    session["my_gold"] = session["my_gold"] + gold
    print session["my_gold"]

elif request.form["casinos"] == building:
    print "sucka"
    gold = random.randrange(0,51)
    print gold
    session["my_gold"] = session["my_gold"] + gold
    print session["my_gold"]


return redirect("/")

app.run(debug=True)`˚`
```

Comment: I can add HTML code if need be!

Comment: I just wanted to say that I really appreciated the use of **sucka** as a debug output.

Comment: lol, yeah I just had a moment!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a hidden text field to each form that identifies which form was submitted by looking at the value of the hidden text field on submission in your python code.

```
<form action="/stuff.py">
    <input type="hidden" name="building" value="casinos">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

In your flask code, instead of looking for a uniquely named component per `elif`, you would just look for the hidden text field and see which value it has:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    session["my_gold"]=0
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/process_money", methods=["post"])
def money():
    if request.form["building"] == "casinos":
        print "I'm gonna get you"
    elif request.form["building"] == "caves":
        print "Bearodactyl, run!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple options:

1. Put a hidden input in each form that sends the type of form it is like:

   `<input type="hidden" name="building" value="houses">`

   then you can run you `if` statements against that value.

**or**

2. Send each form to its own url. Then set up routes in flask that deal with each form independently:

   `@app.route("/process_houses", methods=["post"])`

Comment: each input is set to hidden. When I tried running the statement against the value it only worked for the first input. When I clicked on the the others they through error codes. My assignment states I cant use multiple routes, just the "/" and my "process_money"

Comment: What does you html look like? The hidden inputs should all have the same name and different values so you can test against the value.

Comment: They do have different names, I will change them all to the same

Comment: Right, if you name them all something like `building` you can test with `if request.form["building"] == 'farm'`